# Can running dice explode?

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds you run by rolling a d6 + your pace for movement.  Can this d6 *ace* (otherwise known as explode)?

Comment: What do you mean by "explode"?

Comment: It's a savage worlds concept.  If you roll may in certain situations, you reroll and add the numbers.  Dice can explode any number of times, giving them an infinite distribution.

Comment: The Savage Worlds term is "ace"

Comment: I believe the term 'explode' comes from Feng Shui, where if you have an adventure without an explosion you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Actually, many games call this mechanic as "exploding dice", so it's perfectly fine to use here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No.  Only Trait and damage dice can ace—running dice cannot. (*Savage Worlds Explorer's Edition*, p. 57 ... or p.70 in the *Deluxe Explorer's Edition*)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer as per the rules.

Comment: Besides, consider how ridiculous it would be if the dice kept exploding making the character run half a mile in a single round!

Comment: WELLLL... don't get me wrong, I love Savage Worlds.  However, suddenly running half a klick is really no more ridiculous than someone desperately using a dagger and eviscerating an ogre because the damage dice kept exploding.